# Second query causing only data from it to appear in a while loop

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I am trying to add in a second query to get data from a db table I have called orderdetail. When I do this I get results from both db tables, but I only get the first entry in my orders table to show up for everything.

The only piece of data I am pulling from the orderdetail table is this:

```
<td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row2['ProductName']; ?> </td>
```

Everything else is the orders table and it just repeats the same info. Anyone have any idea why?

```
<?php
//Selecting the data from the table but with limit
$query = "SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM orderdetail LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2);
?>
    <table class="tableproduct">
    <tr>
        <th class="thproduct">Order ID</th>
        <th class="thproduct">Customer Name</th>
        <th class="thproduct">Customer Email</th>
        <th class="thproduct">Date</th>
        <th class="thproduct">Product</th>
        <th class="thproduct">Total Price</th>
        <th class="thproduct"></th>
        <th class="thproduct"></th>
    </tr>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['order_id']) && is_numeric($_POST['order_id'])) {
    mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM orders WHERE order_id = ". $_POST['order_id'] ."")
    or die("Could not DELETE: " . mysqli_error($con));
    "The order was successfully deleted.";
} else {
    Session::flash('order', 'The order was successfully deleted.');
}
if( $result ){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) :

        if( $result2 ){
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) :
                ?>
    <form method="POST" action="orderhistory.php">
        <tr>
            <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['order_id']; ?> </td>
            <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['customer_name']; ?> </td>
            <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['email']; ?> </td>
            <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['date_ordered']; ?> </td>
            <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row2['ProductName']; ?> </td>
            <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['total_price']; ?> </td>
            <td class="tdproduct"><a href='editorderhistory.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>EDIT</a></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<? echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
            <td class="tdproduct"><input name="delete" type="submit" value="DELETE "/></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
<?php
            endwhile;
        }
    endwhile;
}
?>
```

Comment: You're only getting the first because you're having a while in a while. WHILE the second while will loop though all its results in every result from the first while.

Comment: How can I do two while loops simultaneously from both queries?

Comment: `while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2) && $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
//Selecting the data from the table but with limit
$query = "SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM orderdetail LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2);
$data = array();
$data2 = array();
?>
    <table class="tableproduct">
    <tr>
        <th class="thproduct">Order ID</th>
        <th class="thproduct">Customer Name</th>
        <th class="thproduct">Customer Email</th>
        <th class="thproduct">Date</th>
        <th class="thproduct">Product</th>
        <th class="thproduct">Total Price</th>
        <th class="thproduct"></th>
        <th class="thproduct"></th>
    </tr>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['order_id']) && is_numeric($_POST['order_id'])) {
    mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM orders WHERE order_id =  {$_POST['order_id']}")
    or die("Could not DELETE: " . mysqli_error($con));
    echo "The order was successfully deleted.";
} else {
    Session::flash('order', 'The order was successfully deleted.');
}
if( $result ) :
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    if ($result2) {
        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
            $data2[] = $row2;
        }
    }

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $values) :

    ?>

        <form method="POST" action="orderhistory.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $values['order_id']; ?> </td>
                    <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $values['customer_name']; ?> </td>
                    <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $values['email']; ?> </td>
                    <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $values['date_ordered']; ?> </td>
                    <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $data2[$i]['ProductName']; ?> </td>
                    <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $values['total_price']; ?> </td>
                    <td class="tdproduct"><a href='editorderhistory.php?id=<?php echo $values['id']; ?>'>EDIT</a></td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<? echo $values['id']; ?>"/>
                    <td class="tdproduct"><input name="delete" type="submit" value="DELETE "/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

    <?php
    $i++;
    endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

Reworked a bit of your code, but since i can't test it i'm not sure it works, but you can try it out.

It's an different way to do the queries as you can see, since i store the data in arrays before looping though the data, i usually do this so it's easier to understand what's going on if looking at the code later on.

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks this will help me out a bunch in the future.